# RETROFIT :2 Posting modal data to the server

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am new in using retrofit 2 and want to Post data to the server, the data 
i want to send is in modal class and in this modal class i have some fields and an arraylist of data and each of these array element i have an image that needs to be uploaded to the server too.

Do these images in array need to be multipart and if it does how?

Over all i was doing this but didnt work?

```
@POST("send_cheques.php")
Call<Example> SaveCheques(@Body AllCheques cheque_payment);
```

but some thing was wrong

this is what i want to send to server

```
{"ClientId":16,
"CityId":1,
"TotalCheque":2,

 "Cheques":[
 {
  "ChequeAmount": 15000,
  "ChequeNumber":205,
   "ChequeDate": "11/7/18",
   "ChequeImage":"www/ass/img10111"

},
 {
  "ChequeAmount": 21000,
  "ChequeNumber":297,
   "ChequeDate": "14/7/18",
   "ChequeImage":"www/ass/img10111"

}




 ]}
```

this is the modal class

```
public class AllCheques {
@SerializedName("ClientId")
@Expose
public Integer clientid;
@SerializedName("CityId")
@Expose
public Integer cityid;
@SerializedName("TotalCheque")
@Expose
public Integer totalcheque;

@SerializedName("Cheques")
@Expose
public ArrayList<Cheque_Payment> cheques;


public AllCheques(Integer cityid , Integer clientid , Integer totalcheque ,ArrayList<cheques> chequesall){
    this.cityid = cityid;
    this.clientid = clientid;
    this.totalcheque =totalcheque;
    this.chequesall = chequesall;

}

public Integer getCityId() {
    return cityid ;
}

public void setCityId(Integer cityid ) {
    this.cityid = cityid;
}

public Integer getClientId() {
    return clientid;
}

public void setClientId(Integer clientid) {
    this.clientid = clientid;
}

public Integer getTotalcheque() {
    return totalcheque ;
}

public void setTotalcheque(Integer totalcheque) {
    this.totalcheque = totalcheque;
}


public  ArrayList<cheques> chequesall = new ArrayList<>();

public ArrayList<cheques> getChequesall() {
    return chequesall;
}

public void setChequesall(ArrayList<cheques> chequesall )
{
    this.chequesall = chequesall;
}



public static class cheques{

    @SerializedName("ChequeAmount")
    @Expose
    public Integer chequeAmount;
    @SerializedName("ChequeNumber")
    @Expose
    public Integer chequeNumber;
    @SerializedName("ChequeDate")
    @Expose
    public String chequeDate;

    @SerializedName("ChequeImage")
    @Expose
    public String chequeImage;


    public cheques( Integer chequeAmount , Integer chequeNumber ,String chequeDate, String chequeImage)
    {
        this.chequeAmount = chequeAmount;
        this.chequeNumber = chequeNumber;
        this.chequeDate = chequeDate;
        this.chequeImage = chequeImage;

    }

    public cheques() {

    }


    public Integer getChequeAmount() {
        return chequeAmount ;
    }

    public void setChequeAmount(Integer chequeAmount) {
        this.chequeAmount =chequeAmount;
    }

    public Integer getChequeNumber() {
        return chequeNumber ;
    }

    public void setChequeNumber(Integer chequeNumber) {
        this.chequeNumber =chequeNumber;
    }

    public String getChequeDate() {
        return chequeDate ;
    }

    public void setChequeImage(String chequeImage) {
        this.chequeImage =chequeImage;
    }

    public String getChequeImage() {
        return chequeImage ;
    }





}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

For example to upload image on server using `Retrofit`:

```
@MultiPart
@POST("send_cheques.php")
Call<Example> SaveCheques(
 @Query("clientid") String clientid,
 @Query("cityid") String cityid,
 @Query("totalcheque") String totalcheque,
@Part MultipartBody.Part AllCheques cheque_payment);
```

Than:

```
File file = new File(imagePathHere);
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), file);
MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("imageName", "imageName.jpeg", requestBody);
```

Now you can call `SaveCheques` by passing `body` as an argument:

```
 RetrofitAPICalls apiCalls = RetrofitAPIClient.getRetrofit().create(RetrofitAPICalls.class);
Call<Example> uploadPhoto = apiCalls.SaveCheques(clientId, cityId, totalcheque, body);
updateProfile.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {
         if(response.isSuccessful())
          //Image uploaded

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: but does it post all the rest of data with images , i mean all the data above (clientid ,cityid, totalcheque ,arraylist [ chequeamount, chequenumber and the "image" ] .

Comment: Edited answer. Check

Comment: I have an arraylist of class cheque. in this arraylist i have many objects and each object contains an integer cheque amount , integer cheque number , string chequedate and then chequeimages.                                                                              There are many objects in arraylist , also how to pass whole arraylist here.                    File file = new File(imagePathHere); but here i can provide only one image path so i am not understanding the point